# rancher 2.x thru ingress controller returns 404

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

Rancher service:

```
$ kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
rancher      ClusterIP   10.10.17.245   <none>        80/TCP,443/TCP   1h
```

Ingress controller service:

```
NAMESPACE       NAME                   TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)                      AGE
nginx-ingress   nginx-ingress          LoadBalancer   10.10.15.181   <ext-IP>   80:30324/TCP,443:31022/TCP   3h
```

Ingress role:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: rancher-ing
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "rancher"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: api.sample.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: rancher
          servicePort: 443
```

Ingress:

```
$ kubectl get ingress
NAME      HOSTS            ADDRESS   PORTS     AGE
rancher   api.sample.com             80        19s
```

When I am trying to reach rancher over the ingress controller ext-IP:

> $ curl http://api.sample.com

As a response I have some not encoded string. If I do it thru web browser this string will be downloaded and I have got 404.
Similar role for some random service over http (without https) works fine so it's not a matter of wrong ingress controller configuration.

Comment: Could you run Ubuntu Pod using <kubectl run ubuntu --rm -it --image ubuntu --restart=Never --command -- bash> install curl into the Pod using <apt-get update && apt-get -y install curl > and try to access the rancher service using <curl -v http://10.10.17.245> and share the result?

Comment: Poiting to http: `<a href="https://10.10.17.245/">Found</a>.`  
Poiting to https returns json, much better than string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I follow default ingress controller installation:
 https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/blob/master/docs/installation.md
and apply rancher ingress role like:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  labels:
    app: rancher
  name: rancher
  namespace: cattle-system
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - api.sample.com
    secretName: default-server-secret
  rules:
  - host: api.sample.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: rancher
          servicePort: 80
```

This solution enabled https to Rancher UI over the ingress controller without annotations.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "rancher"` you have to deploy your ingress controller with the `--ingress-class=rancher` annotation.

Have a lot at 
https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/master/examples/multiple-ingress-controllers and https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/multiple-ingress/

Cheers