# Ingress return 404

Tags: kubernetes, service, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, rancher

Rancher ingress return 404 to service.

Setup: I have 6 VMs, one Rancher server x.x.x.51 (where dns domain.company is pointing to, TLS), and 5 VMs (one master and 4 worker x.x.x.52-56).

My service, gvm-gsad running in gvm namespace:

```
   apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
 annotations:
   field.cattle.io/publicEndpoints: "null"
   meta.helm.sh/release-name: gvm
   meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: gvm
 creationTimestamp: "2021-11-15T21:14:21Z"
 labels:
   app.kubernetes.io/instance: gvm-gvm
   app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
   app.kubernetes.io/name: gvm-gsad
   app.kubernetes.io/version: "21.04"
   helm.sh/chart: gvm-1.3.0
 name: gvm-gsad
 namespace: gvm
 resourceVersion: "3488107"
 uid: c1ddfdfa-3799-4945-841d-b6aa9a89f93a
spec:
 clusterIP: 10.43.195.239
 clusterIPs:
 - 10.43.195.239
 ipFamilies:
 - IPv4
 ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
 ports:
 - name: gsad
   port: 80
   protocol: TCP
   targetPort: gsad
 selector:
   app.kubernetes.io/instance: gvm-gvm
   app.kubernetes.io/name: gvm-gsad
 sessionAffinity: None
 type: ClusterIP
status:
 loadBalancer: {}
```

My ingress configure: Ingress controller is default one from rancher.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    field.cattle.io/publicEndpoints: '[{"addresses":["172.16.12.53"],"port":443,"protocol":"HTTPS","serviceName":"gvm:gvm-gsad","ingressName":"gvm:gvm","hostname":"dtl.miproad.ad","path":"/gvm","allNodes":true}]'
  creationTimestamp: "2021-11-16T19:22:45Z"
  generation: 10
  name: gvm
  namespace: gvm
  resourceVersion: "3508472"
  uid: e99271a8-8553-45c8-b027-b259a453793c
spec:
  rules:
  - host: domain.company
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: gvm-gsad
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /gvm
        pathType: Prefix
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - domain.company
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: x.x.x.53
    - ip: x.x.x.54
    - ip: x.x.x.55
    - ip: x.x.x.56
```

When i access it with https://domain.company/gvm then i get 404.

However, when i change the service to NodePort, i could access it with x.x.x.52:PORT normally. Meaning the deployment is running fine, just some configuration issue in ingress.

I checked this one: [rancher 2.x thru ingress controller returns 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52442868/rancher-2-x-thru-ingress-controller-returns-404) but it does not help.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: When you are accessing your app via NodePort, you are calling path "/", in Ingress you are calling path "/gvm". Does your app (accessible via service "gvm-gsad") have path `/gvm`? You can try changing `path: /gvm` in Ingress definition to `path: /` and see if it is working. You may also try adding (if you are using NGINX Ingress controller) [rewrite annotation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/). Please let know the results ;)

Comment: @MikolajS. Thank you so so much for your answer! When i change to 'path: /', then it goes to Rancher default page as Rancher is listenning on port 80 and 443. Can you please elaborate more the test cases i should try? Sorry if my questions are silly as I don't have much experience with this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the solution.

The domain.company is pointing to rancher (x.x.x.51). Where the ingress is running on (x.x.x.53,.54,.55,.56).

So, the solution is to create a new DNS called gvm.domain.company pointing to any ingress (x.x.x.53,.54,.55,.56) (you can have LoadBalancer here or use round robin DNS).

Then, the ingress definition is gvm.domain.company and path is "/".

Hope it helps others!